# How do I allow a program to use more CPU in virtual machine running Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu

I do audio processing on Debian Linux, and find that a virtual machine with only one core encodes audio as OGG or AAC just about as fast with eight CPU cores.

Since I lack systematic computer science education, I missed the part about allotting CPU resources, and what I’ve tried so far in Linux seems to be a dead end, so I’ll spare you.

In short, is there a way I can launch an encoder, like [fdkaac](https://github.com/nu774/fdkaac) (non-free) or [oggenc](http://www.rarewares.org/ogg-oggenc.php) so that it will use as much CPU as the system has available?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Realtime kernel if you're only into audio processing. If it doesn't suit you, you can still change the priority level of a process using `nice`. Levels lower (meaning higher priority) than 0 (usually the default) will require root privileges or a specific configuration.

Comment: It's likely your program is running in a single thread/process of execution which means it will only ever be able to use a single core. You may want to look for alternative programs or see if the program has a setting to enable use of multiple cores/processes/threads of execution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188526/why-is-ffmpeg-executable-so-much-faster-than-using-libfdk-aac-directly

Comment: "Sounds like difference in single- vs multi-thread" and thanks, it sounds like the other question was asked by someone w. 8 cores to use! I'll do Thanks, nijave I'll get some stats comparing ffpeg w. fdkaac - but first intend to check that I'll get the same quality as using fdkaac alone. Going to a real time kernel is one of those complexities I intentionally didn't mention, but it does seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In order to benefit from several CPU cores, the encoder program you're using should be written in a special way (with threads). This is not the case for `oggenc`. You can try to use encoders which support threads, like [`mencoder`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mencoder). `mencoder` has a `threads` parameter which you should set to 8 (its default value is 1, meaning no threads).

Another possibility (which is often preferred) is to encode several files at the same time with several instances of encoder running in parallel. In this case, no threads support is required from the encoder itself, as the OS will take care of scheduling encoder processes to available CPU cores.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning GNU Parallel and xjobs in your second paragraph, to schedule the right number of simultaneous workloads over the available cores.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'd like to hear back from the OP first, maybe he has a single file or stream to encode.